# How to use ImageLoader of Volley Library?

Tags: android, image, nullpointerexception, android-volley, loader

I am using volley library to load image from network and getting nullpointer exception. I am using it in Adapter class.Is there any problem in getting instance or what i am not getting. getView() throws nullpointerexception

```html
VolleySingleton.java

package com.w3nuts.babaa.helper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class VolleySingleton {

 private static VolleySingleton instance;
 private RequestQueue requestQueue;
 private static ImageLoader imageLoader;

 private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
  requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

  imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
    new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
     private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(
       20);

     @Override
     public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
      return cache.get(url);
     }

     @Override
     public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
      cache.put(url, bitmap);
     }
    });
 }

 public static VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
  if (instance == null) {
   instance = new VolleySingleton(context);
  }
  return instance;
 }

 public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
  return requestQueue;
 }

 public static ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
  return imageLoader;
 }
}


ServiceListAdapter.class

package com.w3nuts.babaa.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageContainer;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageListener;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.w3nuts.babaa.R;
import com.w3nuts.babaa.getterSetter.ServiceDetailGetterSetter;
import com.w3nuts.babaa.helper.VolleySingleton;

public class ServiceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 private Activity activity;
 private LayoutInflater inflater;
 private ArrayList<ServiceDetailGetterSetter> serviceDetailList;

 // Typeface tfRegular, tfLight;

 public ServiceListAdapter(Activity activity,
   ArrayList<ServiceDetailGetterSetter> serviceDetailList) {
  this.activity = activity;
  this.serviceDetailList = serviceDetailList;
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  return serviceDetailList.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return serviceDetailList.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
 }

 private class ViewHolder {
  RatingBar ratingBar;
  TextView name;
  TextView location;
  TextView rating;
  NetworkImageView image;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  final ViewHolder holder;

  View view = convertView;
  if (convertView == null) {
   inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.service_list_item, null);

   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
   holder.location = (TextView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.location);
   holder.rating = (TextView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.rating_text);
   holder.image = (NetworkImageView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.task_image);
   holder.ratingBar = (RatingBar) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);
   convertView.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }

  holder.name.setText(serviceDetailList.get(position).getTitle());
  holder.location.setText(serviceDetailList.get(position).getLocation());
  holder.rating.setText(serviceDetailList.get(position).getRating() + "");
  holder.ratingBar.setRating((float) serviceDetailList.get(position)
    .getRating());
  // ////VOLLEY IMAGE LOADER
  String url = serviceDetailList.get(position).getImage();
  ImageLoader imageLoader = VolleySingleton.getImageLoader();

  imageLoader.get(url, new ImageListener() {

   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
   }

   public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
    if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
     holder.image.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
    }
   }
  });

  Log.i("title", serviceDetailList.get(position).getTitle());
  Log.i("location", serviceDetailList.get(position).getLocation());
  Log.i("image", serviceDetailList.get(position).getImage());
  // SET TEXT AND IMAGE HERE

  return convertView;
 }
}



Service_list_item.xml

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/task_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/task_demo_image" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at com.w3nuts.babaa.adapter.ServiceListAdapter.getView(ServiceListAdapter.java:93)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-03 18:40:14.909: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at com.andr

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: Also, if your image is a NetworkImageView, you don't need to work with ImageLoader the way you do. Simply call imageView.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);

Comment: Please help me to initialize the imageLoader if this work then i dont need any other stuffs regarding other class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you made `imageLoader` `static`, and you only initialise it in the `VolleySingleton` constructor, which is only called during `getInstance()`.

Make the `imageLoader` non-`static`, and make the `getImageLoader` method also non-`static`, and replace your code to look like this:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).getImageLoader()
```

Comment: I made it static because there were some error in adapter class and it suggested me to make it static...I think you are right an will have to proceed in your solution.

Comment: This Worked...Thanks for giving these much suggstions.